# Горячие клавиши не работают во время цикла. Python

Tags: python, клавиатура, hotkeys

недавно начал писать код на Python. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при начале цилка, программа перестает реагировать на хоткеи из [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)

```
import time
import keyboard
from ahk import AHK

ahk = AHK()

enable = False
count = 0


def start():
    global enable
    global count
    enable = True

    while enable:
        time.sleep(1)
        count = count + 1
        print(count)


def stop():
    global enable
    enable = False
    print("Выключаем скрипт")


def close():
    print("Выключаем программу")
    exit(1)


keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+b', start)
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+p', stop)
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+k', close)
keyboard.wait()
```

Когда я запускаю скрипт и нажимаю на любую из горячих клавиш происходит определенное действие. Но если я нажму на кнопку запуска счётчика, нажать любую другу кнопку во время его работы не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто цикл блокирует работу главного потока, а в нем, похоже, и выполняется обработка нажатий.

Попробуйте в отдельном потоке выполнять цикл.

Пример:

```
from threading import Thread

...

def start():
    global enable
    enable = True

    def run():
        global count

        while enable:
            time.sleep(1)
            count = count + 1
            print(count)

    Thread(target=run).start()
```